# Перенос Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Имеется база на Oracle 11.2.0.4, досталась уже в готовом виде, в установке участие не принимал. Установлена на Linux.
Появилась задача перенести на Winows сервер. Время простоя часа 4 доступно.
Я проделал через rman полный бекап с архив логами. И бекап простым копированием таблиц, redo, control, spfile.
Уже на новом сервере ставлю базу, версия такая же, SID базы такой же.
Таблицы настроил такие же по названиям и количеству при создании базы.
Дальше через rman восстановил spfile и control файлы.

И тут возникает вопрос, как поменять пути к таблицам? Ибо Linux это \app.. Windwos D:..
Если я правильно понял, нужно пересоздать Control файлы?

Comment: Почему вы выбрали путь переноса через RMAN, а не стандартный export/import?

Comment: опыта работа с ораклом неделя, уволился занимающийся этим сотрудник, по этому разбираюсь читаю. Судя документации rman является предпочтительным способом.
Как я понял, вы имеете ввиду перенести все руками на чистую базу с тем же SID на новом сервере и поменять control файлы?

Comment: _Судя документации rman является предпочтительным способом_, где такое указано в документаци? Дайте ссылку, может что-то новое узнаю. Я не имел ввиду руками, а имел ввиду дамп базы экспортировать и имппортировать.